# How to update multiple rows on where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below table data I want to update rows with default **quantity** =1 except max(Sequence) groups on ChildItemID column.
Also I wrote below query.

```
 UPDATE #tempBOM1 SET Quantity=1
    WHERE [Sequence] < (SELECT MAX([Sequence]) FROM #tempBOM1 GROUP BY ChildItemID) and ChildItemID is not null;
```

[image]

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(sequence) over(partition by childItemID) max_sequence
    from mytable t
)
update cte 
set quantity = 1
where sequence <> max_sequence

SELECT * FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use window functions and an updateable CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(sequence) over(partition by childItemID) max_sequence
    from mytable t
)
update cte 
set quantity = 1
where sequence <> max_sequence
```

Comment: Hi , When I wrote select * from cte  after update statement it  says invalid object ct  Please help

Comment: @ShakeerHussain maybe show us your code and tell us the error? (Edit into your question).

Comment: @ShakeerHussain a CTE only exists for one operation, which is the update. After that it is gone. Select from the actual table you are updating.